# Python Add CMD Call to ArgeParse

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, cmd

I am trying to add an option to my help section inside my python code.  When the user runs the cmd call with the -h they will be prompted the following below.

If they do not know what show is available, I want the to choose the option -sl which will run a cmd and output the list as a result in the same terminal.  Because of my inexperience and the cmd involving awk, the quotations are also proving to be an issue.

Untouched command line call is a follows:
jobsinfo --allshow | awk -F "[, ]+" '/jobs/{print $(NF-1)}'

```
showlist = "jobsinfo --allshow | awk -F " + "[, ]+" + "'/jobs/{print     $(NF-1)}'"

# Help section
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Check the render queue for a time period")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--location", default=site, help="The location you want to check. ""#Examples: london, denver, montreal...")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--project", default="New", help="The project you want to check. The Default is set to new. "
                    "#Examples: Please see SHOW list here: http://dnet.dneg.com/display/COMMS/SHOW+INFORMATION")
# parser.add_argument("-sl", "--showlist", action=showlist, help="List the Shows currently on Servers.")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--days", type=int,  default=14, help="The number of days you wish to go back. The default is set to 14 days. "
                    "#Examples: -d 3, -d 9, -d 14")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a few thoughts here for you. As I don't have your `jobsinfo` program, I used the following as the command to run

```
ls -l | awk 'NR < 10 { print " quoting no problem " $NF }'
```

Note, this isn't recommended really, but it was easy to do. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Anyway, for your code given, I only had to make a few changes. The `showlist` option became

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "--showlist",
                    action='store_const', const=True, 
                    help="List the Shows currently on Servers.")
```

This then means that if you use the `-s` option (`./argparse_help.py -s`), then you can do the following:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.showlist:
    print "showlist is True"
else:
    print "showlist is False"
```

See [API reference](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) or [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html#id1) from Python.org if needed.

To actually run the command, you'll probably want the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) module. As an example, I've made use of Pythons raw, multiline strings (`r""" triple quoted strings"""`) to avoid problems with quoting (other than that of the shell, of course):

```
import subprocess
test_run = r"""   ls -l | 
            awk 'BEGIN { 
                    print "'\'' quotes are like they would be in the shell '\''"
                 }
                 NR < 10 { 
                    print  $NF 
                 }'   

           """
subprocess.call(test_run, shell=True)
```

When ran, this gives

```
~$> ./argparse_help.py -s
' quotes are like they would be in the shell '
117984
anvil_group.sh
a.out
argparse_help.py
a.text
awk
bin
Library
confused_out
```

This can mostly be done in Python though, which avoids having to use `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess
print "' quotes are like in python '"
for line in subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']).splitlines()[:9]:
    print line.split()[-1]
```

and output:

```
~$> ./argparse_help.py -s
' quotes are like in python '
117984
anvil_group.sh
a.out
argparse_help.py
a.text
awk
bin
Library
confused_out
```

Hopefully OK to get you going again.